# what is a "covering memo"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What is a "covering memo" in the following context:

> When G.S.O. has been notified, the new G.S.R. receives a kit
>   containing a **covering memo**, The A.A. Service Manual/Twelve Concepts
>   for World Service, useful pamphlets and leaflets, and a literature
>   order form.

[Source](http://www.aa.org/assets/en_US/en_bm-31.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **cover memo** (aka covering memo) is a document that lists the documents in a packet, telling the recipient what he should expect to find. The memo usually states the context of the documents as well, i.e. why they are being sent.